# PHP don't want to echo the characters "<" and ">"

Tags: php, echo

I'm trying to echo this text :

`echo $string = "Hello <username> !";`

But what I get is `Hello !`, it removed my `<username>`.

Do you, please, know how to fix that ?

Comment: Check the source code in your browser, and tell me what do you see

Comment: Oh, `<username>` is considered as a tag, how can I fix it ? http://prntscr.com/f51ai6

Comment: Your browser treats <username>  as a tag that's why you are not showing it on the browser but if you check the source code or the page then you will have it there.

Comment: its not php, its html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this hope this will help you out. Here `<` and `>` are the part of html entities.

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
$string = "Hello <username> !";
echo $string = htmlentities($string);
```

**Output:** `Hello <username> !`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
echo $string = "Hello &lt;username&gt; !";
```

This happened because your browser treated `<username>` as a HTML tag,
You can use htmlspecialchars

[PHP:htmlspecialchars](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php)

Answer (score 1):

replace `<` by `&lt;` and `>` by `&gt;`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe, the php works fine.

**But,** when the HTML is interpreted in your browser, it goes to a `username` tag

Replace `<` and `>` with html entities should work.

```
$string = "Hello <username> !";
echo htmlentities($string);
```

Answer (score 0):

When the `<` and `>` characters are rendered the browser interprets them as a new html tag.  To prevent this from happening you should use the php `htmlspecialchars()` function to translate them into their html entity values ie `&lt;` and `&gt;`.

```
$username = htmlspecialchars("<username>");
echo $string = "Hello $username!";
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php